# Difference between chrome and firefox when using writing-mode vertical

Tags: css, cross-browser

In one div I have 1 span supposed to show a text with a - vertical writing-mode - in the continuity of the horizontal text

The problem is chrome displays the span at the end of the horizontal text and that's what I want and firefox at the beginning and below the horizontal text when i give an absolute position to the container.

```
<div class="logo">Horizontal text<span class="vertical">Horizontal Text</span></div>

.logo {
    position: absolute;
}
.vertical {
     writing-mode: vertical-lr;
     transform:scale(-1, -1);
     display: inline-block;
     margin-left:-20px;
     padding-top:15px
 }
```

---

Answer (score 1):

There isn't enough context in your question to be sure, but I suspect the problem is there is an ancestor element in your layout, probably setting something like `position: relative` that's affecting how your absolutely positioned `.logo` is being rendered.

I [recreated your example in CodePen](https://codepen.io/garykupczak/pen/KKPRRPZ) and in isolation like that the output looks the same to be in both Chrome 76 and Firefox 69.

```
<div class="logo">Horizontal text<span class="vertical">Horizontal Text</span></div>

.logo {
    position: absolute;
}
.vertical {
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    transform:scale(-1, -1);
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:-20px;
    padding-top:15px
}
```

Comment: Ok yes you are right. If you remove the margins and paddings on vertical element, you'll see what I was talking about. I would like it like on Chrome, I have been stuck on this for so long. https://codepen.io/nina-presotto/pen/KKPREQW

Comment: Update : I have added white-space: nowrap on the container and it seems ok now

Comment: Yes, I can see the inconsistency in your latest example. I'm glad you were able to resolve the issue. Would you mind posting your fix as an answer so others can find it more easily?